# PHP/ How to include php code when it's interact with other files

Tags: php, include

I wrote a code about stock management.

I have the files:

index.php

database --> *that contains all my code files*

> When  i'm running my code from localhost/Stock/database/test.php
>   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbHmJ.png)

It runs perfectly and transfers infos with action/post to another codes files without a problem.

And is shows this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTCYU.png)

**Then i include *test.php* in my *index.php*.**

> And  i run ,  this  time  *localhost/Stock* [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCsrT.png)

It displays the same image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYRwF.png)

**But  this time it doesn't work!**

CODE BELOW:

**Index.php**

```
<?php include 'database/database_connection.php'; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<?php
  include 'database/test.php';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**test.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#submit").click(function(){
                var barcode =  $("#kwdikos").val();
                var value  = $("#timi").val();
                $.post("ajax.php", 
                {
                    barcode: barcode ,
                    value: value
                },function(data){
                    $("#test").html(data);

                });


           });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

        <input type="text"   id="kwdikos" placeholder="Εισαγωγή  BarCode">
        <input type="text"   id="timi" placeholder="Εισαγωγή Ποσότητας">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Προσθήκη">
        <p id="test"></p>

        <form action="stock_management.php" method="POST">
        <button id="btn1">Συνέχεια</button>
        </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bootstap Links make AJAX  code to not run too.

Answer (score 0):

I  fixed it.

If someone has the same problem.

Just change the position of my code.

Put Ajax inside the `head`

And delete bootstrap link for ajax.

Also in  post method the actions is `database/ajax.php` because ajax.php is in different folder when i include in *index.php*